# How to push values into 1 row in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with a two dimensional array to store questions and their answers. The problem I'm having is in the way I should push values into it

> ```
> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
> ```

```
var answers = [];
answers[0].push({"value":true, "answer":"4"});
answers[0].push({"value":false, "answer":"3"});
answers[0].push({"value":false, "answer":"2"});
answers[0].push({"value":false, "answer":"1"});
```

How should I link those answers (value and answer text) to specific index that represent the question number?

Comment: answers should be [ [] ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your `0` indexed item is `undefined`. First initialize your `0` indexed item to refer to an array, then call `push` on it

```
var answers = []; // or [ [] ] and omit the next line;
answers[0] = [];
answers[0].push({"value":true, "answer":"4"});
answers[0].push({"value":false, "answer":"3"});
answers[0].push({"value":false, "answer":"2"});
answers[0].push({"value":false, "answer":"1"});
```

Comment: The logic is same - initializing

Comment: yeah, i left the comment before you added the edit, was leaving it there for extra information

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it setup, answers is only a 1 dimensional array.
However, if you want to store both questions and answers, I think a 1 dimensional array will suffice:

```
var answers = [];
answer.push(
    {
        question: "question string", 
        answer: "answer string"
    });
```

In this specific example you should be able to get to the question with

```
answers[0].question
```

or answer with

```
answers[0].answer
```

hope it helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have elements and answers[0] is null. Try adding 
    answers.push([])
before pushing the others